# Conversion of non-uniform distribution to uniform distribution

Tags: math, random, distribution, uniform

How could I change a random non-uniform distribution to a uniform distribution? Is there a formula?

Comment: I think the question is not well formulated. Can you give more details what you want to achieve ? I think also that this is more suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://stats.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Why? Usually it is the other way around, because random numbers are uniform, and need to be transformed to some other distribution.

Comment: Would you care to specify what non-uniform distribution?  I think that would help.

Comment: thanks Andre for the website suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have samples from a random variable X with CDF function F_X.  Then F_X(X) has a uniform distribution.

Comment: oh i see ...Did u mean F(X) = CDF and i need to find the F(X)square ?

Comment: No integration.  Just take samples and stick them into F_X to make uniform samples.  For example, the CDF of an exponential random variable is F(x) = 1 - exp(-x). If you take a bunch of samples x_i from an exponential distribution, the numbers F(x_i) have a uniform distribution.

Comment: Usually this theorem is applied the other way around: it's standard to generate uniform samples and then apply the *inverse* CDF of another distribution family to get samples from that distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is to only use some lower-order bits, which are reasonably uniform.

Comment: sorry i don't really understand what you meant ...care to explain please ? thanks !